# Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDO could not be converted to string on line 35

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to login as user but don't know getting this error but when I try second time I will have access,But after login same this,and after logged in on second try I can't fetch email from DB it seems it not creating session.Its just passing the code not creating sessions.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['email']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {

        $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $password = filter_var($_POST['password'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $password=sha1($password);

        try {
            $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname; dbname=$database", $username, $pass);
            $dbh -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];

            $stmt = $dbh -> prepare("SELECT email, password FROM tbl_user WHERE email = '".$email."' and password = '".$password."'");
            $stmt -> bindParam('".$email."', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt -> bindParam('".$password."', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt -> EXECUTE();
            $em = $stmt -> fetchColumn();

            if ($em == true) {
                // session_register("email");
                // session_register("password");

                $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
                $_SESSION['START'] = time();

                setcookie("username", $_POST['email'], mktime()+(60*3), "/");
                setcookie("LUS", time(), mktime()+(60*3), "/");

                $stmt -> $dbh -> prepare("SELECT Name FROM tbl_user WHERE email = '".$email."'");
                $stmt -> EXECUTE();

                $em2 = $stmt -> fetchColumn();
                echo "Logged in.";
            } else {
                echo "email or password is incorrect.";
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "".$e->getMessage();
        }
    } elseif (empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
        # code...
        echo "Error : Enter your E-mail.";
    } elseif (!empty($_POST['email']) && empty($_POST['password'])) {
        # code...
        echo "Error: Enter your Password";
    } else {
        echo "Error: Enter your E-mail & Password";
    }

}
elseif (isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
    # code...
    echo "Welcome again you still logged in <strong>" .round((time() . $_SESSION['START'])/60) ."</strong> minutes(s) ago <a href='logout.php'>LogOut</a>";
}
elseif (!isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
    # code...
    echo "You must loggin first.";
    //header('location:../index.php');
}
```

Comment: theres no use of preparing the statement if you're just going to directly substitute user input into the query string. it just defeats the purpose :-(

Comment: kindly guide me upper preparation or lower?

Comment: i suggest you start over and reading up http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers#Running_Statements_With_Parameters it'll help you to properly use prepared statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change second prepare statment usage

```
  $stmt -> $dbh -> prepare("SELECT Name FROM tbl_user WHERE email = '".$email."'");
```

to

```
  $stmt = $dbh -> prepare("SELECT Name FROM tbl_user WHERE email = '".$email."'");
```

Comment: can you guide me the hoe can I show the name of user logged in?